# How to measure execution time for prediction per image (keras)

Tags: time, keras, execution, predict

I have a simple model created with Keras and I need to measure the execution time for prediction per image. Right now I just do this:

```python
start = time.clock() 
my_model.predict(images_test)
end = time.clock()

print("Time per image: {} ".format((end-start)/len(images_test)))
```

But I noticed that the calculated time is bigger when len(images_test) is smaller. For example when len(images_test) = 32 I get: 0.06 and when len(images_test) = 1024 I get: 0.006

Is there a "right" way to  do this ?

Comment: You're probably doing it the right way. And yes, it should be natural to have an overhead time (time the model takes to do other things in order to initialize and finish the processing). It should also be natural to process many images faster due to parallelizing (especially in GPUs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if use TF it seems no Asynchronous problem 
but if use pytorch it has Asynchronous problem. 
in TF:

```
start = time.clock() 
result = my_model.predict(images_test)
end = time.clock()
```

in pytorch:

```
torch.cuda.synchronize()
start = time.clock() 
my_model.predict(images_test)
torch.cuda.synchronize()
end = time.clock()
```

But i think you can do 10 times Loop model_predict 
and print time_list 
(computer need load keras model so first time load slower than other times )

in TF:

```
pred_time_list=[]
for i in range(10):
    start = time.clock() 
    result = my_model.predict(images_test)
    end = time.clock()
    pred_time_list.append(end-start)
print(pred_time_list)
```

(print the pred_time_list and you may find out why the times incorrect)

Reference:

[1]  
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/doing-qr-decomposition-on-gpu-is-much-slower-than-on-cpu/21213/6

[2] 
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-there-any-code-torch-backends-cudnn-benchmark-torch-cuda-synchronize-similar-in-tensorflow/51484/2